# MUI icons render with default color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render the Google icon which is inherited from `@mui/icons-material/Google`
but by default the icon is using my custom theme's primary color even after applying the style property to the icon. Here is the code below

```
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@mui/material";
import GoogleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Google";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

type Props = { text: string };

const ColorButton = styled(Button)<ButtonProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  textTransform: "capitalize",
}));
const ButtonOutlined = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <ColorButton
      variant="outlined"
      startIcon={<GoogleIcon style={{ color: "inherit" }} />} //this icon renders with the theme primary color
    >
      {props.text}
    </ColorButton>
  );
};

export default ButtonOutlined;
```

Below is my custom theme

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    color: {
      primary: string;
      secondary: string;
      tertiory?: string;
      warning?: string;
      notify?: string;
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    color?: {
      primary?: string;
      secondary?: string;
      tertiory?: string;
      warning?: string;
      notify?: string;
    };
  }
}

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: "#309de6" },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the **color** property is set to 'inherit', which instructs the icon to inherit its color from its parent element. Since the parent element specifies the color as the theme's primary color, the icon ends up inheriting this primary color from the parent.

However, if you explicitly set the color property to 'black' or any 'other' color, as shown below:

> const ColorButton = styled(Button)(({theme}) => ({
> color: 'black',   textTransform: 'capitalize', }))

This ensures that the icon will always appear in that color, regardless of the theme's primary color.